# Drupal 7 Use media selector from the media module in custom module

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, media

I am creating my own module that will send an email to a specific address.

But I need to know how I can incorporate the media selector from the module called 'media' so the user can upload a file to the server in the same form as sending the email from.

My form at the moment is created in the PHP of my new module.

```
$form['email'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Your e-mail address'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['title'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Title of bug'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
 $form['message'] = array(
'#type' => 'textarea',
'#title' => t('Bug description'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit'),
);
  return $form;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`media.module` defines a Form API element type called `media`. So you can do something like the following:

```
$form['file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'media',
  ...
);
```

Take a look at `media_element_info()` in `media.module` for further options.

Comment: if I want to use this only for images how do I do that \

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code. It works even on more than one media element in one form.

```
$form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'media',     
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#description' => t('Image'),
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#media_options' => array(
      'global' => array(
        'types' => array('image'), // Example: array('image', 'audio');
        'schemes' => array('http'), // Example: array('http', 'ftp', 'flickr');
      ),
    ),
    '#default_value' => array('fid' => ''), // Change to your default value
);
```

Comment: For Media 2.x it simply is `'#default_value => $my_fid,`, no array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup the entire media form, you could use,

```
$form['pgh'] = array(
'#type' => 'media',
'#title' => t('Upload video'),
'#input' => TRUE,
'#media_options' => array(
  'global' => array(
    'types' => array('document'),
    'schemes' => array('http'),
  ),
),
'#description' => t('Pick a video file to upload.'),
'#attached' => array(),
'#extended' => TRUE,
// '#value' => array('fid' => 22),
);
```

the last '#value' set the default file uploaded last time. Hope this helps.